# Sum Columns SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sum columns called `Tax Paid`, `Interest Paid`, `Penalty Paid`, and `Balance Due`. And then group by so that I have one line of data.

```
SELECT PRIMARY_OWNER AS 'Taxpayer Name / Doing Business As',
       BILL_NUMBER AS 'Taxpayer Id / Bill Number',
       IN_CARE_OF_NAME AS 'In Care Of',
       ADDRESS_LINE1 AS 'Address Line 1',
       ADDRESS_LINE2 AS 'Address Line 2',
       ADDRESS_LINE3 AS 'Address Line 3',
       CITY AS 'City',
       RIGHT(STATE, 2) AS 'State',
       POSTAL_CODE AS 'Zip',
       PWA.BILLING_DATE AS 'Bill Date',
       CASE
           WHEN LEVY_TYPE_CODE IS NULL
                AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION'
                AND LEVY_TYPE = 'LEVTTAX'
           THEN DIS.AMOUNT
           ELSE '0.00'
       END AS 'Tax Paid',
       CASE
           WHEN LEVY_TYPE_CODE = 'LEVTINTEREST'
                AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION'
           THEN DIS.AMOUNT
           ELSE '0.00'
       END AS 'Interest Paid',
       CASE
           WHEN LEVY_TYPE_CODE IS NULL
                AND LEVY_TYPE = 'LEVTLLFEE'
                AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION'
           THEN DIS.AMOUNT
           ELSE '0.00'
       END AS 'Penalty Paid',
       CASE
           WHEN SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'PAYMENTRELEASE'
           THEN DIS.AMOUNT
           ELSE '0.00'
       END AS 'Amount Released',
       CURRENT_BILL_DUE_AMOUNT AS 'Balanace Due'
FROM EXTBLM_BILL_MASTER AS PWA
     INNER JOIN PTABLM_BILL_MASTER AS BILL ON PWA.BILL_PK = BILL.BILL_PK
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PTASBT_SUBTRANSACTION AS SBT ON BILL.BILL_PK = SBT.ALLOCATION_TYPE_REFERENCE_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PTADIS_DISTRIBUTION AS DIS ON SBT.SUBTRANSACTION_PK = DIS.SBT_SUBTRANSACTION_PK
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PTAGLA_GL_ALLOCATION AS GL ON DIS.GLA_GL_CODE_ALLOCATION_ID = GL.GL_CODE_ALLOCATION_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PTALAC_LEVY_ACCOUNT AS PAYLAC ON GL.ACCOUNT_ID = PAYLAC.LEVY_ACCOUNT_PK
WHERE BASE_NUM = '0000793569'
      AND PAYLAC.TAX_DISTRICT = 'JURSBUN'
      AND TAX_YEAR = 2017;
```

Below are the results that I am receiving...

[image]

Comment: So what the problem / question is?

Comment: Your outer joins don't work. In an outer joined row the `PAYLAC.TAX_DISTRICT` is null and can hence never match `'JURSBUN'`. Move conditions on outer-joined tables to their `ON` clause or inner join them right away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT  
PRIMARY_OWNER AS 'Taxpayer Name / Doing Business As'  
, BILL_NUMBER AS 'Taxpayer Id / Bill Number'  
, IN_CARE_OF_NAME AS 'In Care Of'  
, ADDRESS_LINE1 AS 'Address Line 1'  
, ADDRESS_LINE2 AS 'Address Line 2'  
, ADDRESS_LINE3 AS 'Address Line 3'  
, CITY AS 'City'  
, RIGHT(STATE, 2) AS 'State'  
, POSTAL_CODE AS 'Zip'  
, PWA.BILLING_DATE AS 'Bill Date'  
, SUM(IIF(LEVY_TYPE_CODE IS NULL AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION' AND LEVY_TYPE = 'LEVTTAX', DIS.AMOUNT, 0)) AS 'Tax Paid'  
, SUM(IIF(LEVY_TYPE_CODE = 'LEVTINTEREST' AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION', DIS.AMOUNT, 0)) AS 'Interest Paid'  
, SUM(IIF(LEVY_TYPE_CODE IS NULL AND LEVY_TYPE = 'LEVTLLFEE' AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION', DIS.AMOUNT, 0)) AS 'Penalty Paid'  
, SUM(IIF(SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'PAYMENTRELEASE', DIS.AMOUNT, 0)) AS 'Amount Released'  
, SUM(CURRENT_BILL_DUE_AMOUNT) AS 'Balanace Due'  
FROM EXTBLM_BILL_MASTER AS PWA  
        INNER JOIN PTABLM_BILL_MASTER AS BILL ON PWA.BILL_PK = BILL.BILL_PK  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PTASBT_SUBTRANSACTION AS SBT ON BILL.BILL_PK = SBT.ALLOCATION_TYPE_REFERENCE_ID  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PTADIS_DISTRIBUTION AS DIS ON SBT.SUBTRANSACTION_PK = DIS.SBT_SUBTRANSACTION_PK  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PTAGLA_GL_ALLOCATION AS GL ON DIS.GLA_GL_CODE_ALLOCATION_ID = GL.GL_CODE_ALLOCATION_ID  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PTALAC_LEVY_ACCOUNT AS PAYLAC ON GL.ACCOUNT_ID = PAYLAC.LEVY_ACCOUNT_PK  
WHERE BASE_NUM = '0000793569'  
        AND PAYLAC.TAX_DISTRICT = 'JURSBUN'  
        AND TAX_YEAR = 2017  
GROUP BY PRIMARY_OWNER  
        , BILL_NUMBER  
        , IN_CARE_OF_NAME  
        , ADDRESS_LINE1  
        , ADDRESS_LINE2  
        , ADDRESS_LINE3  
        , CITY  
        , STATE  
        , POSTAL_CODE  
        , PWA.BILLING_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! The data is all on one line and the data is summing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT PRIMARY_OWNER AS 'Taxpayer Name / Doing Business As',
   BILL_NUMBER AS 'Taxpayer Id / Bill Number',
   IN_CARE_OF_NAME AS 'In Care Of',
   ADDRESS_LINE1 AS 'Address Line 1',
   ADDRESS_LINE2 AS 'Address Line 2',
   ADDRESS_LINE3 AS 'Address Line 3',
   CITY AS 'City',
   RIGHT(STATE, 2) AS 'State',
   POSTAL_CODE AS 'Zip',
   PWA.BILLING_DATE AS 'Bill Date',

   sum(Tax Paid), 
   sum(Interest Paid), 
   sum(Penalty Paid),
   sum(Balance Due)

   CASE
       WHEN LEVY_TYPE_CODE IS NULL
            AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION'
            AND LEVY_TYPE = 'LEVTTAX'
       THEN DIS.AMOUNT
       ELSE '0.00'
   END AS 'Tax Paid',
   CASE
       WHEN LEVY_TYPE_CODE = 'LEVTINTEREST'
            AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION'
       THEN DIS.AMOUNT
       ELSE '0.00'
   END AS 'Interest Paid',
   CASE
       WHEN LEVY_TYPE_CODE IS NULL
            AND LEVY_TYPE = 'LEVTLLFEE'
            AND SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'BILLALLOCATION'
       THEN DIS.AMOUNT
       ELSE '0.00'
   END AS 'Penalty Paid',
   CASE
       WHEN SUB_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'PAYMENTRELEASE'
       THEN DIS.AMOUNT
       ELSE '0.00'
   END AS 'Amount Released',
   CURRENT_BILL_DUE_AMOUNT AS 'Balanace Due'
FROM EXTBLM_BILL_MASTER AS PWA
 INNER JOIN PTABLM_BILL_MASTER AS BILL ON PWA.BILL_PK = BILL.BILL_PK
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PTASBT_SUBTRANSACTION AS SBT ON BILL.BILL_PK =     SBT.ALLOCATION_TYPE_REFERENCE_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PTADIS_DISTRIBUTION AS DIS ON SBT.SUBTRANSACTION_PK = DIS.SBT_SUBTRANSACTION_PK
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PTAGLA_GL_ALLOCATION AS GL ON DIS.GLA_GL_CODE_ALLOCATION_ID = GL.GL_CODE_ALLOCATION_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PTALAC_LEVY_ACCOUNT AS PAYLAC ON GL.ACCOUNT_ID = PAYLAC.LEVY_ACCOUNT_PK
WHERE BASE_NUM = '0000793569'
  AND PAYLAC.TAX_DISTRICT = 'JURSBUN'
  AND TAX_YEAR = 2017;
Group by PRIMARY_OWNER, 
   BILL_NUMBER,
   IN_CARE_OF_NAME,
   ADDRESS_LINE1,
   ADDRESS_LINE2,
   ADDRESS_LINE3,
   CITY,
   STATE,
   POSTAL_CODE,
   PWA.BILLING_DATE
```

Comment: What did you change, and why do you think that resolves the problem? A good answer would explain this.